# Boolean Attribute Update with Devise and Rails' Check Box Helper Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I've added a borrower boolean and lender boolean to my database under User model. I want the user to be able to choose whether they're a borrower or lender through a check box when they sign up (Devise).

```
%p Are you a Borrower or Lender?
= f.check_box :borrower
Borrower
= f.check_box :lender
Lender
```

The boolean value remains unchanged after checking the relevant box and submitting the form.

```
class AddBorrowerToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
 add_column :users, :borrower, :boolean, :default => false
end
end
```

Edit:

The log states `Unpermitted parameters: borrower, lender`.

How do I extend the Devise controller to permit those?

Solution:

Created a new controller and included the new params.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

private

def sign_up_params
params.require(:user).permit(:borrower, :lender, :email, ...)
```

Also, how do I make them choose between either a borrower OR a lender, so that they can't choose both?

Comment: You will find the strong_params method in devise or in your controller. Please post it.

Comment: yes! thank you. I did it a little differently but you're totally right. posted the solution  above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
%p Are you a Borrower or Lender?
= f.check_box :borrower, {}, "true", "false"
Borrower
= f.check_box :lender, {}, "true", "false"
Lender
```

***Update:***

> Unpermitted parameters: borrower, lender

You will have to customize the default devise `strong_params` method to ***permit*** `borrower`, `lender`. Something like below.

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit( :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name, :borrower, :lender ) }
end
```

Comment: @liroy Can you update your post with the controller code and server log please?

Comment: @liroy Don't post here. Please update in your question with the log and controller code(specifically strong_params code).

Comment: Okay. Anyway, the controller is from Devise so I don't have it.